# Why is my rails app at example.com:3000 and not example.com?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a rails app but it appears at example.com:3000, how do I make it appear at example.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably because you are running the development app on its default port.

Go through the [deployment process](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy) for your live system.

Comment: I have followed the tutorial at linode for installing passenger here http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/ubuntu-10.04-lucid#sph_installing-passenger-and-dependencies, is there something else I need to do also?

Answer (score 1):

If you run your app with `rails server` you can run it with `rails server -p 80` but you must be root and this solution is not good for production. You'd better use a solution provided by Quentin's link.

Comment: I use this approach when I'm working on several snapshots of a project at once (juggling is fun!). But I use ports that start at 300 and increment by 10. I agree that this is only a development thing. In production Quentin is right...